# Finding $f(x)$ in $\cos^2(x)f(x)=x^2-2\int_1^x \sin(t)\cos(t)f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I need to find a valid $f(x)$ such that:

$$\cos^2(x)f(x)=x^2-2\int_1^x \sin(t)\cos(t)f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

I can apply the FToC and I get:

$$(2\cos(x)-\sin(x)f(x))+(\cos^2 x f'(x))=2x\sin(x)\cos(x)f(x)$$

Now I don't understand how to find $f(x)$.

Comment: What does $drt$ mean? What is $sen(t)$?

Comment: I don't know nothing about $t$, it's $dt$

Comment: @ZainPatel Spanish (?) for $\sin$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your equation reads $f(x)\cos^2 x = x^2 - 2\int_1^{x} \sin t \cos t f(t)\, \mathrm{d}t$ then differentiating gives $$-2 f(x) \sin x\cos x  + \cos^2 x f'(x) = 2x - 2f(x)\sin x\cos x $$ so upon simplification, this gives us $f'(x)\cos^2 x = 2x$ which is a differential equation you can solve $$f(x) = \int \frac{2x}{\cos^2 x} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int 2x\sec^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x$$ using IBP or some other technique you fancy. In particular, IBP gives $$\int 2x \sec^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x = 2x \tan x - \int 2\tan x \, \mathrm{d}x$$